# camel does not stop converting message

Tags: spring, apache-camel, converters

I have a problem within one of my camel routes. It is a route that handles soap requests and does some exchanges...
After the exchange the route just hangs and after setting logging to TRACE I found out, that camel does an endless converting, that never stops:

> 2015-09-24 10:24:03,227 [TRACE]
>   (org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter:231) -
>   Converting org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage -> java.lang.String
>   with value: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message:
>   Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message:
>   Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: [Body
>   is null] 2015-09-24 10:24:03,230 [TRACE]
>   (org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter:231) -
>   Converting org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage -> java.lang.String
>   with value: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message:
>   Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: [Body is null] 2015-09-24
>   10:24:03,232 [TRACE]
>   (org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter:231) -
>   Converting org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage -> java.lang.String
>   with value: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message:
>   Message: Message: Message: Message: [Body is null] 2015-09-24
>   10:24:03,234 [TRACE]
>   (org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter:231) -
>   Converting org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultMessage -> java.lang.String
>   with value: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message: Message:
>   Message: Message: Message: [Body is null]
>   ...

This seems to happen after an exchange, before sending the message to an remote soap endpoint.

Strangely I have some other routes, where this works without hanging in the endless loop.

I just updated to camel 2.15.3, but this still happens.
I'm using java 7 and tomcat 7.

How can I find out, where the problem is and how to fix this?
Thanks, C

Comment: You can debug the code. Set a breakpoint in that DefaultTypeConverter line 231 and see what happens

Comment: I already tried that, but debugging is a mess. I get error messages from eclipse like: "org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException: Timeout occurred while waiting for packet 36502. occurred resuming thread.". But I'll try some more, hopefully I can get any information...

Comment: No, I can not get any information from debugging. At some point (before the interesting stuff) my cpu goes to the roof and it take ages to go to a next step... What should I do here?

Answer (score 0):

I found out, why the endless converting happened: It was our proxy server, that blocked the request being send to the forreign endpoint...